# Need download file from URL in my custom path Programmatically by java in SWT

Tags: url, eclipse-plugin, swt, wizard, launch

I am using below code to open url and download something from this url. After that downloaded file should be save in my path mentioned in second parameter.But by this code when i perform download, the download file saved on browser default setting path. How to save download file to my own path.

```
 Program.launch(url,my path);
```

Answer (score 0):

`org.eclispe.swt.Program.launch(url,path)` opens the default operating system executable associated with the url (the browser in your configuration). The second parameter is the [working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) for the executable and has nothing to do with the download directory of your browser.

If you only want to download something from an url please look at [how-to-download-and-save-a-file-from-internet-using-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921262/how-to-download-and-save-a-file-from-internet-using-java).